# How can i call to specific index of tabs in ionic 3.20 from child page?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angularjs-directive, ionic3, hybrid-mobile-app

Suppose,
i have tabs page which contained 3 index page. Index page 1 is home page and index page 2 is products page and index 3 is cart page. When i nav push to search page from home page , there is a button. I wanted to click that button to go to directly tabs index page 3. How can it possible?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post the relevant code, so we're no longer supposing and having something concrete to think about ;)

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to import Tabs from ionic-angular in your **search.ts**

```
import { NavController, Tabs } from ionic-angular;

export class SearchPage {
// then assign the navctrl parent to the tab
    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public tab: Tabs) {
        this.tab = this.navCtrl.parent;
    }

    // create a method that will be called after click
    goToTab(){
        this.tab.select(3); // depends on what index of the tab you want to go
    }
}
```

In your **search.html**

```
<button (click)="goToTab()"> To other tab </button>
```